# What is considered a bounding box area

Tags: circles, area

I am bit confused and couldn't find the answer anywhere. So basically, if I want to find the bounding box are of a circle which one is considered the bounding box area is it the whole area of the square or it's the ****area of the square - area of the circle**?**

And if it is the second approach **area of the square - area of the circle** then does it mean that the bounding box of a square is 0?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2467.png)

Comment: What’s a bounding box?

Answer (score 0):

if $(start_x,start_y)$ are the top-left corner of bounding box and $(end_x, end_y)$ is the bottom-right corner of the bounding box, then for each $x\in S$, if x's coordinates are $(x_0,y_0)$, then it follows that:

$$start_x<x_0$$
$$start_y<y_0$$
$$end_x>x_0$$
$$end_y>y_0$$

When this procedure is done for every $x\in S$ then you have bounding box in your hands.

The above shows the situation in 2d, but 3d case isn't much different.